# Due to changes in angular 2 rc.6 jspm bundling no longer works

Tags: angular, jspm

due to changes in angular 2 rc.6 bundling no longer works!
As you can see from the changes in rc.6:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

this was a major overhaul with a bunch of references even in the change log to how systemjs is now used. As a result,  we can no longer use the command:

`jspm bundle src/App.js ./dist/index.js --minify --skip-source-maps`

as this results in the following error:

```
[08:40:33] 'x_bundle' errored after 18 s
[08:40:33] Error: Command `jspm bundle src/App.js ./dist/index.js --minify --skip-source-maps` failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
Command `jspm bundle src/App.js ./dist/index.js --minify --skip-source-maps` failed with exit code 1
[08:40:33] 'production' errored after 31 s
[08:40:33] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(x_bundle)'
Message:
    Command `jspm bundle src/App.js ./dist/index.js --minify --skip-source-maps` failed with exit code 1
Details:
    killed: false
    code: 1
    signal: null
    cmd: jspm bundle src/App.js ./dist/index.js --minify --skip-source-maps
    stdout:      Building the bundle tree for src/App.js...

    stderr:
err  Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: string (./src/platform-browser-dynamic) (line: 2345, col: 16, pos: 104806)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1545:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1553:11)
    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2092:9)
    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2100:9)
    at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2106:9)
    at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2126:56)
    at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2317:73)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2186:19)
```

let me add that this is the line of failure `export * from './src/platform-browser-dynamic';` in /src/platform-browser-dynamic

it is almost as if now minification is failing due to how ng2 rc.6 is working, but I am not sure as there are so many moving parts...

this worked perfectly prior to rc.6

I hope someone from the team can assist as we can not go to production until we get this resolved,

regards

Sean.

Comment: Maybe not the issue, but try with mangling disabled.

Comment: yes disabled it... same :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After banging my head against the wall for days I finally upgraded my jspm to 0.17. Then instead of bundle use

`jspm build src/App.js ./dist/index.js --minify --skip-source-maps`

Everything should work as expected after that. This solution will work provided you are running typescript version 1.8.34.

Comment: I am suspecting that angular2 and or typescript 2.0 broke the jspm bundle

Comment: You are right about the typescript version. I can confirm I am using typescript version 1.8.34  with RC6 and can bundle without issues

Comment: I wonder how did you jspm to embed in your HTML and CSS as you are using rollup via build command and mine does not seem to embed them

Answer (score 1):

after spending 2 days trying to fix jspm with bundling I was finally able to fix it, in jspm you need to remove from packages the statement of :

`packages: {
 "@angular/common": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/compiler": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/core": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/http": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/platform-browser": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/router": {
            "main": "index.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        }
        ...`

I have no idea what changed in ng2 prior to rc.6 that would require this removel, but here you go, this fixes it and now I can FINALLY run:

`jspm bundle app/main ./dist/index.js --minify --skip-source-maps`

hopes it helps someone

Sean